# adding http headers to SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Is there a way to add in custom http response headers to the response from SSRS? 
Something similar to adding the following to an IIS web.config file? 
I tried adding it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER2016\Reporting Services\ReportServer\web.config but it doesn't work.

```
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
```

This is on Windows 2016 running SQL Server 2016.

The follow solution is not god for me..

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SQL 2016 but is possible with 2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15